# Header letters overlap when using narrow resolutions

Tags: html, css, font-size

I'm adding bootstrap to my website and I noticed that, when I use a narrow resolution (windows size) my header overlaps. If my header is small in size, like the usual H1 size, there's no problem. But when using a large size (check CSS below) the problem exemplified in the image happens.

How can I solve it? Is there any property like vertical spacing, or something like that? I'm a newbie with css. A possible workaround is to use [Fittext](http://fittextjs.com/).

CSS code:

```
.nevis-font {font-family: 'Nevis', Tahoma, sans-serif;}
.ultra-head {font-size: 7.8em;}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <br/>
        <h1 class="text-center nevis-font ultra-head">DIOGO NUNES</h1>
        <br/><br/><br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify `line-height`:

```
.nevis-font {
    font-family: 'Nevis', Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
.ultra-head {
    font-size: 7.8em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

- Do NOT use line-height in pixels, it doesn't scale. Use unitless values (or percentages or ems but that's equivalent).
- Do not set `line-height` below 1 either.
- Default value is around 1.3 or 1.4
- [accessibility guidelines recommend at least 1.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html)
- there are reasons when you want to use a line-height of 1 but that's when you are CERTAIN that there won't be 2 lines of content. Rare cases

Font makers are free to do whatever they want with the baseline and other properties embedded in font files: script fonts can span over 3 lines of text for some fancy effect if they want! (I believe).
tl;dr with exactly the same typography parameters, each font and character within will occupy different heights and widths and etc

EDIT: are there negative margins anywhere to be seen in Firebug?

Comment: A `line-height` of 1.0 was enough. Thx!